# axios cancel is not working in react native redux

Tags: react-native, axios

I am using axios for api call in react native application. I have redux for managing state in the application. I am trying to cancel the axios request when the component is unmounted but it is not cancelling.

```
import axiosMaker from '../../axios'

useEffect(() => {
    const source = axios.CancelToken.source()
    props.fetchFile(fileName, source.token)

    return() => {
        console.log('un mounting document view')
        source.cancel()
    }
},[])

//redux action
export const fetchFile = (location, token) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
            dispatch(fetchFileRequest())
            const config = {
                path : location,
            }
            let axiosObj = await axiosMaker()
            try{
                axiosObj.post('download', config,
                    { 
                        headers :{ 
                            'authorization' :  `Bearer ${accessToken}`
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        cancelToken: token
                    }
                )
                .then(async response => {
                    console.log('doucment view success')
                    dispatch(fetchFileSuccess(response.data))
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('doucment view failure')
                    dispatch(fetchFileFailure(error))
                })
            } catch(error){
                if(axiosObj.isCancel(error)){
                    console.log('request is canceled')
                }
                console.log('hello world')
            }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? How to cancel the axios call in redux?

Answer (score 0):

I was sending accessToken and cancelToken separately. I sent it together.

```
        axiosObj.post('download', config,
            { 
                headers :{ 
                    'authorization' :  `Bearer ${accessToken}`
                },
                cancelToken : token
            }
        )
```

and another changes is isCancel() function is available in the axios object itself not in the customize axios object. So, I imported the axios

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

and called isCancel function in this object, not in the axiosMaker object.

```
            if(axios.isCancel(error)){
                console.log('request is canceled')
            }
```